# Knockout JS, TextArea add value while data-bound to attr ID

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Good afternoon Folks.

I am new to knockout JS, so don't laugh if it is too easy for you :(

I want to add some Text I Get to the content of the textarea and I want to keep my data-bind attribute Id as well..

anyone?

```
 <script type="text/html" id="A-Template">
        <tr>
        <td>
                <h3> Some text </h3>
                <textarea class="Some_Class"  data-bind="attr:{id: ID}"> 
                **data-bind="value: SomeText"** 
                </textarea>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
```

say my ID is 4 and my Sometext is "A LONG TEXT"

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can data-bind many members just use a comma to separate them:

```
<textarea class="Some_Class"  data-bind="attr:{id: ID}, value: theText">
```

Comment: Waw so we can pass two arguments like that :( I knew it would be something silly that I don't know .. :(

Comment: I suggest going through the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com to get the hang of this stuff :)